# What is the proper way to handle concatenation of data returned from multiple http observables in angular2/4 rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have 5 different URLs that each return data in the from of an array of objects. I want to concat these objects into a single array that I store local to my ANgular2 componenent. Right now, I do something like this in my ngOnInit:

```
this.myHttpService.graburl1data()
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            if(!this.mylist) {
                this.mylist = []
                this.mylist = this.mylist.concat(response);
            } else {
                this.mylist = this.mylist.concat(response);
            }

            this.myHttpService.graburl2data()
                .subscribe(
                    response => {
                        if(!this.mylist) {
                            this.mylist = []
                            this.mylist = this.mylist.concat(response);
                        } else {
                            this.mylist = this.mylist.concat(response);
                        }
                    });
        });
```

There has to be a better way, please help!

Comment: use mergeMap to  combine the response

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45229861/2545680) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two requests and each returns an observable that emits **an array** as a stream value:

```
const response1 = of([1, 2, 3]);
const response2 = of([4, 5, 6]);
```

You want to get those values as a stream of values - flattened. You can use a combination of operators to do that:

```
const merged = merge(response1, response2).mergeMap((a) => {
  return a;
});

merged.subscribe((v) => {
  console.log(v);
});
```

You will get the following output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

You can read more about the `merge` operator [here](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/merge).

In your case you will obtains the `response` observables by calling the `http`:

```
const response1 = this.myHttpService.graburl1data(),
const response2 = this.myHttpService.graburl2data()
...
```

So, the final code is:

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

const merged = merge(
  this.myHttpService.graburl1data(),
  this.myHttpService.graburl2data()
).mergeMap((a) => {
  return a;
});

merged.subscribe((v) => {
  console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: If Im not wrong, mergeMap((a) => {
  return from(a);
}); could just be return a, if what you are looking for is to flatten the array

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, `a` is an array, so only one value (array) will be emitted without `from`, I need `from` to turn it into a stream of values

Comment: Yeah, but mergeMap flattens the array into singular values https://jsfiddle.net/41awjgda/30/

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, you're right, thanks, I didn't know `mergeMap` could work with plain data, I thought it was specific to observables. I updated my answer)

Comment: How to do it if i'm building loading of additional element on infinite scroll? So i don't know in advance how many request i need to merge in one observable..

Comment: @aholbreich, can you create a separate question with details

Answer (score 3):

Your snippet seems to suggest that there is no dependency between the requests, so you can use `forkJoin` to peform them in parallel:

```js
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin";

Observable.forkJoin(
  this.myHttpService.graburl1data(),
  this.myHttpService.graburl2data()
)
.subscribe(
  (responses) => {
    // ... responses[0] is the response from this.myHttpService.graburl1data
    // ... etc.
  }
);
```

`responses` will be an array of the responses in the order in which the request observables were passed to `forkJoin`.

If you want the requests performed in series, use `concat` and `toArray` instead:

```js
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/concat";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toArray";

Observable.concat(
  this.myHttpService.graburl1data(),
  this.myHttpService.graburl2data()
)
.toArray()
.subscribe(
  (responses) => {
    // ... responses[0] is the response from this.myHttpService.graburl1data
    // ... etc.
  }
);
```