# Combine requests in series - Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, rxjs6

I'm trying to chain a few requests in a series, something like `forkJoin` but the requests NOT being requested in parallel. Here's what I have so far:

```
let nodeDetails = this.http.get('node/1/')
let nodeParents = this.http.get('nodeParents/1/')
let nodeTree = this.http.get('nodeTree/1/')
let nodeUsers = this.http.get('nodeUsers/1/')
let nodeDocuments = this.http.get('nodeDocuments/1/')
var requests = [nodeDetails, nodeParents, nodeTree, nodeUsers, nodeDocuments]
forkJoin(requests)
  .subscribe(responses => {
    // List of all responses from all of the requests
    console.log(responses)
  })
```

I read somewhere that `concat` can be used in combination with `toArray`, but that was apparently taken out in recent rxjs updates. Is there any way to do this currently?

**EDIT** - The final goal is something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45229853/7970018). The code in that answer is no longer working in Angular 7 and Rxjs 6.2.2.

Comment: So you can use [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) or [concat] (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) depending on your requirement s of maintaining order (or not).

Comment: Just use `concat`

Comment: So I just read through the documentation for `concat` and `merge` again, and here's the issue. I need the responses in a single array - I don't want to subscribe to each response as it arrives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what ended up working:

```
import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

let nodeDetails = this.http.get('node/1/')
let nodeParents = this.http.get('nodeParents/1/')
let nodeTree = this.http.get('nodeTree/1/')
let nodeUsers = this.http.get('nodeUsers/1/')
let nodeDocuments = this.http.get('nodeDocuments/1/')
const requests = concat(nodeDetails, nodeParents, nodeTree, nodeUsers, nodeDocuments)

requests
    .pipe(toArray())
    .subscribe(responses => {
        // Array of responses
    })
```

The `toArray()` operator waits for all responses - in the order provided in `concat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat` from **Rxj6**. Tyry something like that:

```
//  RxJS v6+
import {concat} from 'rxjs';

let nodeDetails = this.http.get('node/1/')
let nodeParents = this.http.get('nodeParents/1/')
let nodeTree = this.http.get('nodeTree/1/')
let nodeUsers = this.http.get('nodeUsers/1/')
let nodeDocuments = this.http.get('nodeDocuments/1/')

const requests = concat(nodeDetails, nodeParents, nodeTree, nodeUsers, nodeDocuments)
```

The use `forkjoin` for parallel or Rxjs operator, like `concatMap` for non-parallel